# Python Executable not Running in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created a python script in VS Code that runs perfectly fine.

I am trying to turn it into an executable for ease of access and use.

I have a macbook air m1 and everything should be up to date.

I installed pyinstaller with `pip install pyinstaller`.

When I run `pyinstall #filename` I get everything to run fine including the python executable inside the folder.

I have also tried `pyinstaller --windowed #filename` and it works fine as well according to the stuff that pops up.

When I run the executable my terminal opens for half a second and spews something and then it dissapears. When I check my taskbar I see terminal still open so I click on it. it shows just a blank terminal and I cannot scroll up to see what was running before hand.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong that is causing the exe to not run but when I run `python3 #filename` in the terminal everything runs fine.

Any help would be appreciated

I have tried not a whole lot because I am not sure what the error really is

I expect that when I run the python exe that was created I will get the terminal opening up and the first lines of my code asking for user input will run.

instead I get the terminal opening up and getting some gibberish I do not have time to read and then the terminal blanks out and I cannot see what it did.

Comment: IF you want to create an excutable from the python script, probably the most portable solution would be to cretae a package an use the console_scripts to create the executables that you need. The  executable is created when the package is installed and will be portable since you could as well define the package requirements

Comment: Without debugging details, there is no way to tell what's wrong. If you run the compiled app from a terminal window, you should be able to see the error messages.

Comment: create a [example]

Answer (score 0):

This is **5 step** the process that i use (which works for windows):

Can you verify that steps 1 & 2 are done correctly ? And also that you have done the `ios` version of the `windows` commands.,,

1. **Add Python to Windows Path:**
   An easy way to add Python to the path is by downloading a recent version of Python, and then checking the box to 'Add Python to PATH' at the beginning of the installation.
2. **Install the PyInstaller Package:**

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

3. **create a script:** Here is an example.

```
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

def hello ():  
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= 'Hello World!', fg='blue', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(150, 200, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Click Me', command=hello, bg='brown',fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

4. **Create the Executable using PyInstaller:**
   go to the Command Prompt and type: `cd` followed by the *location where your Python script is stored*.

   then type:
   pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
5. **Your executable will be created at the location that you specified:**
   There will be a subfolder called `dist` and the executable will be there.

Answer (score -1):

for my personal reference I use Anaconda + Jupyter notebook for developing. Then I usually save the jupyter notebook where the code resides as a python script as .py. After that I can use this executable python script into anything as I need. run is from task scheduler, I can run it manually, from the shell, or anything based on the scenario